# Android Dagger 2 and MVP injecting inside an injected object

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2

I want to use Dagger 2 with MVP pattern. So I have this scenario, each `View` has its own `Component` e.g.  `MyFragment` has a component like this:

```
@PerFragment @Component(dependencies = ActivityComponent.class, modules = MyFragmentModule.class)
public interface MyFragmentComponent {
  void inject(MyFragment fragment);
}
```

And in `MyFragmentModule`, I provided a presenter and a model which will be used in `MyFragment`

```
@Module public class MyFragmentModule {

  @Provides @PerFragment public MyPresenter providePresenter() {
    return new MyPresenter();
  }

  @Provides @PerFragment public Model provideModel() {
    return new Model();
  }
}
```

Now I'm injecting component in `MyFragment`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
       @Inject MyPresenter presenter;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    component = DaggerMyFragmentComponent.builder()...build();
    component.inject(this);
  }
}
```

Also `MyPresenter` is look like this:

```
   public class MyPresenter {

      @Inject Model model;
}
```

**Question**

I don't know how to inject `Model` in my presenter. I don't want to injecting a component in my presenter like what i did in `MyFragment`.

Is there any way for this approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering field injection must be manually called through the component, you need a reference to your component. Of course, you shouldn't legitimately *create a new component* in your Presenter, I think what you ought to do is provide the class that holds the reference to the component.

Please check the EDIT for the proper solution.

```
@Module
public class MyFragmentModule {
    private MyFragment myFragment;

    public MyFragmentModule(MyFragment myFragment) {
        this.myFragment = myFragment;
    }

    @Provides
    public MyFragment myFragment() {
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Provides @PerFragment public MyPresenter providePresenter(MyFragment myFragment) {
        return new MyPresenter(myFragment);
    }

    @Provides @PerFragment public Model provideModel(MyFragment myFragment) {
        return new Model(myFragment);
    }        
}

public class MyPresenter {
    @Inject Model model;

    public MyPresenter(MyFragment myFragment) {
        myFragment.getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Your other alternative is constructor injection.

```
public class MyPresenter {
    private Model model;

    public MyPresenter(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}

    @Provides @PerFragment public MyPresenter providePresenter(Model model) {
        return new MyPresenter(model);
    }
```

EDIT: A third solution would be to skip module with your Presenter altogether, and just use `@Inject` annotated constructor.

```
@PerFragment
public class MyPresenter {
    private Model model;

    @Inject
    public MyPresenter(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
 }
```

Or

```
@PerFragment
public class MyPresenter {
    @Inject
    Model model;

    @Inject
    public MyPresenter() {
    }
 }
```